# How to turn off battery charging/discharging alert sound?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, power-management, alsa, battery

My laptop has a problem that it continuously connects and disconnects the charger. Ubuntu 20.04 gives a sound alert every time it happens. I want to turn this off. I have searched for a way, but the answers suggest turning off the alert sound. I have found no option to do so from settings. I have found that `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false` command will disable alert sound, but I want to turn off charging alert sound only.

Answer (score 1):

so easy 1>go to setting 2>select notification 3>select power 4>turn off the sound alert